# Unable to zip using 7z in batch file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Here i'm using batch file to take backups & then zip those backups.Backup process successfully.But zipping process failed and it always show to install the 7zip.But i already installed 7ip.

Here goes my code

```
@ECHO OFF
osql -S .\sqlexpress -E -i "C:\Sql_Backup.sql" -o "E:\test\testbk.sql"
ECHO.
7za a -tzip "E:\test\newfile.zip" "E:\test\newfile.Bak"
ECHO.
del "E:\test\newfile.Bak"
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

What does "*it always show to install 7zip*" mean?  Are you seeing an actual error message?  Is the error message this?

```
'7za' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If so, that's because the program is `7z`, not `7za`.  Just change it in your batch file and see if it starts working...

Comment: When i run batch file,everytime 7zip installation wizard comesup

Comment: Put the `pause` command on the line after 7z - is there an error message?

Comment: I think 7za is "7-zip for Applications".  Are you sure you have installed the correct version of 7-zip?  (http://7-zip.org)

Answer (score 1):

May be system couldn't find where your 7z.exe is, so just tell your system where your compressing program is by giving the correct path like below:

```
C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a -tzip "E:\test\newfile.zip" "E:\test\newfile.Bak"
```